# How to get blob data in json or xml format?

Tags: php, mysql, json, xml

I have stored xml file in mysql BLOB datatype,so now i want to get that data in xml or json format and need to display.

i tried like this,but getting binary values

```
  $mqs = db_select('multiple','mq')
     ->fields('mq',array('data'))
     ->condition('tokenid', '1')
     ->execute();
    foreach ($mqs as $row) {
        $test = base64_encode($row->surveyid);  //here junk binary data displaying 
            drupal_set_message("data ::".$test);
                $xml = simplexml_load_string($test);
                $json = json_encode($xml);
                $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
            drupal_set_message("data::".$json);         
    }
```

actual data not displayed in XML or JSON formats?

any other alternatives?

Comment: I guess `base64_encode()` is a good start, but you don't specify how your data is supposed to be "displayed", and what kind of data it even is. Not to mention that we know nothing about what's inside those $row variables.

Comment: xml format ata stored in blob.

Comment: tried with base64_encode(),but it  displayed binary data.not original data